# Is there a connlimit module for ip6tables?

Tags: firewall, iptables

Does anyone know if there is a connlimit module that can be used for ip6tables?
Please let me know.

Thanks,
Kenneth

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here it is (it may need a kernel patch):

ip6tables  -p  tcp  --syn  --dport  80 -s fe80::/64 -m connlimit
              --connlimit-above 16 --connlimit-mask 64 -j REJECT